# C++ class design question

Tags: c++, oop

this is a question about which class does a free on shared pointers.

So I have a class hierarchy, `base` and `derivedA` and `derivedB` and `derivedC` all from `base`. Base has some virtual functions.

I have a class, `Holder`,  it has a collection that holds instances of `derivedA`, `derivedB` and `derivedC`. So an instance of `Holder` is created, instances of the derived classes are dynamically created and add their pointers to the containers. I add the pointers so I can iterate through the container and call `base->virtualFunction`. I `new` the objects because otherwise an instance created on the stack is destroyed when it goes out of scope.

```
class Base;
class DerivedA : public base;
class DerivedB : public base;
class DerivedC : public base;


class Holder {
    std::vector<Base*> collection;
    void add(Base* base);
}

Holder holder;
DerivedA* da = new DerivedA;
DerivedB* db = new DerivedB;

holder.add(da);
holder.add(db);
```

who is to call `delete` on `da` and `db`?

Any other way to design this for the deletion concern goes away?

Thanks
Reza

My question is first off, which class should be responsible to free the dynamically created the derived classes? The class the contains the list

Comment: Please fix your code snippet: for instance, what is it a `std::vector` of?

Comment: Please post real code, not pseudo code.

Comment: managing the scope and lifetime of dynamically created objects has been the topic of discussion for decades.  The answer is, "it depends" - it depends on who else uses them, how you want to manage them, if you want to use things like smart pointers, etc.  There is no "one size fits all" answer.  Some people are very diligent about ensuring they have no memory leaks and can write and maintain code with dynamic allocations - and others do a poor job - so GC languages make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Tim: on the other hand, sometimes you need to make the lifetime as short as possible, and there GC struggles. In C++, because of determinstic lifetime of objects, we have SBRM (or RAII the ill-named). Many languages provide work-around for the lack of SBRM (using clauses, finally clauses, with clauses, defer statements to name a few), but none have the intrisic beauty of defining the cleanup *once* (in the destructor of the class) and none (that I know) offer the class designer to constraint uses this way to avoid leaks.

Comment: @Matthew - I prefer managing the lifetimes myself.  I use consistent patterns for lifetimes of the objects and I am not a fan of the non-deterministic GC either.  (especially for some specific problem domains)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpler way ? Change your vector to become *aware* of ownership.

```
boost::ptr_vector<Base>
```

is such a vector, especially suited for polymorphic data:

- deep-copy through clone methods (just implement `virtual Base* clone() const;`)
- automatic memory management
- sugar coating on dereferencing iterator (yields a `Base&` instead of a `Base*`)

In C++11, another alternative could be `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Base> >`.

Comment: Assuming he doesn't actually want to share the resource and only wants to use polymorphism this is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

If *you* use `new`, then *you* have to say `delete` to clean up.

Your design suffers from the problem that you store the result of `new`, which you absolutely must keep track of, in a container, and it is unclear what can happen to it there. The container may be emptied or replaced or copied at some other point. In the end, *you* have to clean up, but how do you determine *what* to clean up?

Your design is inherently *non-local*, which means that the task of tracking the pointers now requires full understanding of everything that you do to the container. This is a heavy maintenance burden and limits scalability.

The better design approach would be to wrap the result of `new` into a single-responsibility manager like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` and store *those* in the container. That way, it is always completely clear who owns the manually allocated objects and who disposes of them should the reference become inaccessible or lost.

---

[*Original Update:*] As a suggestion for your original design, which may or may not be appropriate (depending on many other factors you're not telling us about), and notwithstanding all its shortcomings, you could make the `Holder` do the cleaning up, and specify in the contract that you promise to `add` only pointers that you created with `new`:

```
Holder::~Holder() {
  for (auto it = collection.cbegin(); it != collection.cend(); ++it)
    delete *it;
}
```

This requires a strong contract between the class and the user, so do be sure that you intend this, that you document it, and most importantly that you write or delete copy constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question (not my downvote, though).

Comment: I upvoted it but it is really more of a comment, than an answer.

Comment: Well, OP asks "who has to clean up" -- that's intimately tied to "who allocates". I think this answer entails the correct strategy, but in the absence of more specific information, the answer can't be any more specific, either.

Comment: Your suggestion is quite error prone, the user of the class `Holder` has to remember/know that it will free every added object. Either it creates new copies and frees them (but again the caller is responsible for their disposal) or it does not touch them, leaving the burden to the caller.

Comment: @Ricardo: As I said, this requires a strong contract and documentation, and it's certainly not very elegant. My first sentence encapsulates the general principle you have to follow, though.

Comment: I added some reasoning on why the OP's design is inherently flawed and suggested an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to for manual memory management, you need to define who is going to be responsible for deleting.

One possibility is for `Holder` to assume ownership of the classes and then to clean up in `~Holder` (calling `delete` for every element in the vector). But then you would also need to decide on how `Holder` is going to be copied (deep copy or flat copy). The second option would require you to keep track of all `HolderS` that have references to the same memory etc.

Short and simple: Go with a `shared_ptr` or avoid this situation all together. Those are available in C++11 enabled compilers or from the Boost libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The responsibility to free the memory is of the class/method that knows whether those objects are still used/useful.

In your simple example code `Holder` only contains pointers to the objects, so he can't possibly know when to free the memory: the pointed objects could be still useful even after `Holder holder` is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do has been implemented in a sane and proven way by [Boost Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm), I strongly recommend always to first look at boost.org if this hasn't been done by it, already.

Comment: Likely because boost is heavy weight and not intuitive and adds a huge dependency to projects.  I did not vote it down - but I disagree with "boost is the answer" for everything.

Comment: I upvoted it but boost isn't always the answer.. maybe that's why it got downvoted.

Comment: @Tim: even if it's not the answer, it's worth checking how it was done. Also... *do not forget* that you can always extract just a substract of Boost, you're not obliged to take it whole.

Comment: @Tim: I agree that one shouldn't mindlessly use the things offered by boost. But in the case of Shared Pointers, I'd say, use what Boost has to offer, since trying to implement this on one's own this kind of thing is difficult to get right (and even harder if it should be thread safe).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, class-wise, the level you use the "new" is the level you use the "delete".
In your case the allocated vars in the program are in "main" I guess, so the allocation is not part of the class behavior therefor no class should free them but the user himself.